# Passing a function of type reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror as parameter to a method

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a class with a method that takes a function as parameter. This function is the strategy that determines how a file is split into chunks. This is the signature of the method.

```
def split(r: RemoteFileInfo, append: Boolean, workDir: File, strategy: (Long) => Int = defaultStrategy): LinkedHashSet[Chunk] = {
  ...
}
```

There is a companion object that provides a number of predefined strategies. I want to make the strategy configurable by adding it to a configuration file. This is a snippet from the configuration file.

```
downloader {
    ...
        dependencies {
            ...
            splitterStrategy = "ratioStrategy"
            ...
        }
 }
```

This is my test code:

```
object Strategy {
    def ratioMinMaxStrategy(fileSize: Long): Int = fileSize.toInt
}

def splitTest(strategy: (Long) => Int): Unit = {
    println(s"strategy result=${strategy(100L)}")
}

splitTest(Strategy.ratioMinMaxStrategy)
```

This is the code I use to load the strategy function using reflextion:

```
val instanceMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).reflect(Strategy)
val strategyMethod = ru.typeOf[Strategy.type].declaration(ru.newTermName("ratioMinMaxStrategy")).asMethod
val strategy = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(strategyMethod)
strategy(100L)
strategy(200L).asInstanceOf[Int]
```

The code works individually, but when I combine it i get an error 'type mismatch;  found   : reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror  required: Long => Int'.

```
splitTest(strategy)
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this?

Regards, nidkil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the type mismatch error message says, you have given a `MethodMirror` that contains an apply method of type `(Any*) => Any`. This apply method passes its arguments to the method you want to call through reflection - in your case a function of type `Long => Int`.

Because the compiler can't do a conversion from `(Any*) => Any` to `Long => Int` automatically, you have to do it manually:

```
val strategyFunc: Long => Int = strategy(_).asInstanceOf[Int]
splitTest(strategyFunc)
```